# Where do the girls' names come from?

Tags: character, zombieland

In Zombieland the four main characters are Columbus, Tallahassee, Wichita and Little Rock. It's my understanding that the first two are named because that's where they're trying to get to.

The pair introduce themselves via where they're from

> Where are you headed?
>   Columbus.
>
> You?
>      Tallahassee.

Later Tallahassee refuses to give his name

> What's your name?
>
> Stop, no names. Keeps us from getting too familiar

However we're never given a reason behind the names of the two sisters. Throughout the whole film Little Rock and Wichita want to go to a theme park yet this doesn't seem to reflected in either of their names?

Comment: And I thought those were the characters' origins (though I think the girls were supposed to be sisters, which would make it strange for them to come from different parts of the country).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I've added some bits from the script to explain why I think they're destinations

Comment: Ok, but one might still think they are just heading there because they are from there. But I also admit that I don't know it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson makes sense, I was just trying to follow the pattern

Comment: This was answered on the Sci-Fi SE site: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32855/how-were-wichita-and-little-rock-named

Comment: @JohnnyBones why don't you add it as an answer with a bit detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Zombieland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombieland#Character_names) Wikipedia page-

> The main characters do not use each other's real names, but identify
>   themselves using place names (Columbus, Tallahassee, Wichita, Little
>   Rock) that relate to them. This includes Columbus's neighbor, named
>   406 after her room, and his fictional sexual conquest "Beverly Hills",
>   as well as Sister Cynthia Knickerbocker, whom Columbus identifies as a
>   "Zombie Kill of the Week" winner, and whose surname is actually an
>   obsolete term for a citizen or inhabitant of New York City. There is
>   one exception in Bill Murray playing himself. At the end of the film,
>   Wichita tells Columbus that her real name is Krista.

So, it means that character names are not based on their desired destination but to their related places. May be birth place or the city they used to live in. Both the sisters doesn't give any detail about their birth place. So all are assumptions at the moment.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't clocked the other references. All makes sense now!